# Can we deploy ASP.Net Web Applications on a Client Computer like a Software?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, web-deployment, iis-express

I have tried looking for a way in which we can deploy a web application on a clients computer like a software and of methods in which we can update that web application. I have given the whole scenario below.. Any suggestions / recommendations in best architecture to use are also welcome!

[image: Architecture of my App]

Comment: You could use a deployment tool like [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com) to keep the local app up to date, but this wouldn't help with initial setup. Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: @RichardEverett I am already doing the complex App development for the online version, I want to use the same App Code with slight changes for local instead of duplicating efforts in WPF

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1000 Users for Your Application They all need a working local(IIS server) to run your app on browser ,as was well as a Sql server to store local data while user in offline, i think this is too expensive,...i don't have idea about any other alternative

[deploy website on local iis](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32210/Deployment-of-a-Website-on-IIS)

[MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972)

Comment: 1000 different Clients who will have upto 10 users each, yes they would need IIS, I was asking to know a way of how to deploy it